# How can I update the data in my list if a subitem updates from a get request in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

So I have the general concept of RTK query down fairly well but I have a use case where I need some assistance.

I have a list component and a details component that you can navigate to to view more details on that list item. So I have two endpoints getList and getDetails.

My question is, if I load the list and another user updated the db for that same list, when I view the details on that updated item I would see the new data, but if I navigate back to the list it would not show that new data that was received from getDetails endpoint

So in summary:

1. getList and display the list in one component
2. A different user updates item 1 in db while I have already loaded my list
3. I navigate to the details component for item 1 and getDetails shows that new data
4. I navigate back to the list component and the old data is still shown for item 1

How can I get the new data from getDetails to update the data in getList for item 1?

```
tagTypes: ["ItemList"],
endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getList: builder.query<ListResults, RelisTables>({
        query: (table) => `data/${table}`,
        providesTags: (result) => {
            return result?.list?.items.length
                ? [
                        ...result?.list?.items.map(({ details: { id } }: any) => ({
                            type: "ItemList" as const,
                            id,
                        })),
                        { type: "ItemList" as const, id: "LIST" },
                  ]
                : [{ type: "ItemList" as const, id: "LIST" }];
        },
    }),
    getDetails: builder.query<ListResults, RelisDetails>({
        query: ({ id, table }) => `data/${table}/${id}`,
        providesTags: (result, error, { id }) => [{ type: "ItemList" as const, id }],
    }),
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky way of doing it but I do believe I'm just dumb and backed myself into an unnecessary corner.

Effectively I listen for the incoming getDetails request to be completed then dispatch a queries/queryResultPatched action. I got the inspiration for my modifications from [this post from the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates#using-the-oncacheentryadded-lifecycle).

```
getDetails: builder.query<ListResults, RelisDetails>({
        query: ({ id, table }) => `data/${table}/${id}`,
        providesTags: (result, error, { id }) => [{ type: "ItemList" as const, id }],

        // Hacky way of updating item from list should it have changed
        // between getting the list and then getting new details.
        // Maybe there is a better way of doing this but I am not sure how.
        async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { cacheDataLoaded, dispatch, getCacheEntry, getState }) {
            await cacheDataLoaded;
            const data = getCacheEntry().data?.list.items[0];

            if (data) {
                dispatch(
                    relisApi.util.updateQueryData("getList", undefined, (response) => {
                        const position =
                            response.list.items.length &&
                            response.list.items.findIndex((item) => {
                                return item.details?.id && item.details.id.toString() === arg.id;
                            });

                        if (position > -1) {
                            response.list.items[position] = data;
                        }
                    })
                );
            }
        },
    }),
```